# Laravel 5.7 - Filter a paginated query builder by an accessor?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, builder, laravel-5.7

I have a query builder that returns paginated data:

```
$builder = Example::latest();
        $examples = $builder->with([
                                'activity',
                                'followers',
                                'messages',
                                'assignedTeam',
                                'domain',
                                'history'])
                        ->paginate();

        return response()->json($examples);
```

The model has an accessor, `isRelativeTo` that is a boolean value. I want to filter this by `!isRelativeTo`. I know I can't map over it or add a filter directly, as it's not a collection, so wondering what the correct way of doing something like this might?

Here is my accessor logic:

```
public function getIsRelativeAttribute($value)
{
    $user = auth('api')->user();

    return $this->assigned_user_id == $user->id || $this->reported_by == $user->id
        || $user->teams()->where('id', $this->assigned_team_id)->exists();
}
```

Comment: Can you add your accessor logic?

Comment: Sure! I'll add it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating scopes in addition to the accessor. In case anyone is curious:

```
/**
 * Scope the query relative to the authenticated user
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @param \App\User $user
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeRelativeTo($query, User $user)
{
    $teamIDs = $user->teams->pluck('id');

    $query->where('assigned_user_id', $user->id)
        ->orWhere('reported_by', $user->id)
        ->orWhereIn('assigned_team_id', $teamIDs);
}

/**
 * Scope the query NOT relative to the authenticated user
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query
 * @param \App\User $user
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
public function scopeNotRelativeTo($query, User $user)
{
    $teamIDs = $user->teams->pluck('id');

    $query->where(function ($q) {
        $user = auth('api')->user();
        $q->whereNull('assigned_user_id')
          ->orWhere('assigned_user_id', '!=', $user->id);
    })
   ->where('reported_by', '!=', $user->id)
   ->whereNotIn('assigned_team_id', $teamIDs);
}
```